# Laravel Cookie get value

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get cookies data but i'm getting as output the follow array:

```
"s:7:"MaSP5Jd";"
```

Code for get the Cookie value:

```
$referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');
```

The output must be only: MaSP5Jd
Can someone help me to get this output good out?

For set the Cookie i have created middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if (! $request->hasCookie('referral') && $request->query('ref') ) {
      $response->cookie('referral', encrypt( $request->query('ref') ), 525600 );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: How you set your cookie? code please

Comment: I have add the set cookie middle ware code in main post

Answer (score 1):

You can set on Session like this :

```
Session::put('referral', "MaSP5Jd");
```

Code for get the Session value :

```
Session::get('referral'); // output "MaSP5Jd"
```

Comment: Output for Cookie::get(referral); is "s:7:"MaSP5Jd";" I don't know where its going wrong.

Comment: Insert `Session::put('check', "data");` now whats the output???  `Cookie::get('check');`

Comment: Thats works but its only for the current session, For referral i need to use Middleware. Can you explain with middleware where to add this Session?

Comment: I have add it inside main post.